# How to get edge indices from selection?

Tags: python, api, maya, mel, pymel

Is there's a way to get the indices properly from a Pymel/Maya API function?

I know Pymel has a function called `getEdges()` however according to their docs this get's them from the selected face, however I just need them from the selected edges.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you're voting this down, can you please at least tell me why? I don't understand...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your answer will work theodox, I did find a much simpler resolution, after some serious digging!

Turns out, hiding and not very well documented, was a function ironically called `indices()`, I did search for this but nothing came up in the docs.

**Pymel**

`selection[0].indices()[0]`

The above will give us the integer of the selected edge. Simple and elegant!

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you just the expanded list of selected edges?  That's just FilterExpand -sm 32 or cmds.filterExpand(sm=32) or pm.filterExpand(sm=32) on an edge selection. Those commands are always strings, you grab the indices out them with a regular expression:

```
# where objs is a list of edges, for example cmds.ls(sl=True) on an edge selection
cList = "".join(cmds.filterExpand( *objs, sm=32))
outList = set(map ( int, re.findall('\[([0-9]+)\]', cList ) ) )
```

which will give you a set containing the integer indices of the edges (I use sets so its easy to do things like find edges common to two groups without for loops or if tests)

Comment: I also found I can do it like this `self.edgeIndex1 = int(selection[0].split('[')[1].split(']')[0])` however it's quite ugly for something that could be so simple right? `selection[0].getEdgeIndex()` Are you sure there's nothing else? haha

Comment: Apart from doing set tests -- supported here -- there's not much use for integer indexes over components : anything you do with maya needs to know both the object and the component, which you get with ls or filterexpand.

Comment: I did find a better solution but I upped your answer! Please see my answer! :)